# FFmpeg Stream Transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, flash-media-server

I have got a streaming application that displays the stream sent from a Flash Media Server.
I want to grab that stream and transcode it to a output stream with a different bitrate using ffmpeg.

Could such kind of thing be done using ffmpeg?

Comment: Could you specify the command for the same...?

Comment: Sure, but your question is a bit vague right now. You'll need to add more info. What do you mean by 'output stream'? Is that an output file or what? I'll give you an answer anyway, but I have no idea if it's what you have in mind right now.

Comment: I needed to create an output stream rather than a file... 
And that transcoded stream could than be passed on to a OSMF MediaPlayer object or a video object to get displayed...

Answer (score 1):

This will get input from a feed, and transcode it to an MKV file with default audio and video codecs, and 1024k bitrate for the video stream (audio bitrate is specified with '-ab'):

```
ffmpeg -i "http://my_server/video_feed" -b 1024k output.mkv
```

For a live feed try this (not sure if it'll work, I don't have ffmpeg to test it right now):

```
ffmpeg -i "http://my_server/input_video_feed" -b 1024 -f flv "http://my_server/output_video_feed"
```

This should create a FLV feed.

Comment: That could do...
But could it be possible to output a transcoded stream rather than a file which can eventually could be fetched by a OSMF MediaPlayer or Video object...

Comment: OK, but what is the output format/video codec/audio codec? Also what is the input like? Meaning the input container format, the audio codec and the video codec? Anyway, see my answer, I've edited it.