# Stream Video from Raspberry Pi to my Webpage

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, raspberry-pi2, omxplayer

I want to live stream the video captured on my SJ 4000 Camera.

The Camera is Connected to my Rpi by Wi-Fi and the stream is available using the following address: **rtsp://192.168.1.254/sjcam.mov**

Now, I want to watch this stream in my webpage by using a Streaming Engine on Raspberry Pi.

The **rtsp://Camera addr** works when I Connected the Camera directly to my Windows PC and attempted using VLC. But I wanted to do it by using Rpi as the streaming engine.

I have attempted the following:

1) Using ffmpeg -i "rtsp://[IP_ADDR]" -vcodec -f http://[my_pc_IP_ADDR]
    But am getting an error message "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http://192.168.55.39:5678".

2) Installed OMX Player. But I do not find proper material to stream using OMX Player.

3) Have come across GStreamer. But still the same problem..I did not find proper material.

Kindly provide your valuable inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can launch thttpd or any other HTTP server on the Pi then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431714/ffmpeg-transcode-to-live-stream) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve) might work for you - both answers describe how to use ffmpeg to transcode RTSP to an HLS playlist. If running a HTTP server is not an option then you need to combine ffmpeg and ffserver - the are numerous examples (i'll update the answer if I find one that fits your case).